# How do I delete the first 3 characters in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How might I tell mysql to..

delete the first 3 characters from mytable.title only where the first 3 characters are numbers 01-10 followed by a space?

Example..

Delete any record in the 'title' column that looks like this:

```
01 California
09 Texas
10 Idaho
```

Leave the records alone that don't start with a number and space (such as these):

```
California
Texas
Idaho
```

I have several thousand records that I want to remove these preceding numbers from.  Thoughts?

Comment: what about rows where title is `24 texas`?

Comment: and while we're at it: what have you tried?

Comment: the numbers are only 01-10.  Please read the description before answering.

Comment: i have not answered per se, i have asked a question for clarification. you did not state that these numbers couldn't exist. no need to be snappy.

Comment: also, at one point in your question, you write `delete the first 3 characters from mytable.title`. later, you write `Delete any record in the 'title' column`. which is it? does the 3 characters go? or does the title go (become empty?) or does the whole record (i.e. line) go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table SET title=SUBSTRING(title, 4) WHERE title REGEXP '^[0-9][0-9] ';
```

Comment: Note that this will remove the numbers from the beginning of the title, but not delete those rows. After another read of the question, it appears that's not what you want.

Comment: isn't it SUBSTRING(title, 3) ?

Comment: Nope. The second parameter to `SUBSTRING` is the character you want to  start from and MySQL starts indexes at 1.

Comment: oops... sorry, didn't see your answer. mine is almost identical to yours D:

Comment: You gave me exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly.  Sorry that I strayed off base in my example.  I seen that it was worded wrong now.  Thank you soooo much for your help!