# MySQL Remove first two characters of all fields

Tags: mysql, substring

I have some data that looks like this:

```
C:10
R:200
N/A
E:3
N/A
N:77
```

I'm trying to remove the first two characters for each row, and skip the rows with `N/A` I've been trying to figure out how to do this with `SUBSTRING` but have had no luck.

```
UPDATE d1
SET d1_val = SUBSTRING(d1_val, 1, LENGTH(d1_val)2)
```

Comment: Instead of `N/A`, you should use `NULL` (not a string, the real null) in your database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete the first 3 characters in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860376/how-do-i-delete-the-first-3-characters-in-mysql)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE d1
SET d1_val = SUBSTRING(d1_val, 3)
WHERE d1_val <> 'N/A'
```

Answer (score 8):

More safe query regarding multiple executes is using `LIKE '_:%'`:

```
UPDATE d1
SET d1_val = SUBSTRING(d1_val, 3)
WHERE d1_val LIKE '_:%'
```

It will change every line which looks like `C:10`, `E:100` etc. but not `10`, `100` after one previous query run.

(Assuming there is always one letter before `:`. If more - use `LIKE '%:%'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE d1
SET d1_val = SUBSTRING_INDEX(d1_val , ":",-1);
```

Does the job also, leaves "N/A" as it is.

Answer (score 1):

use `SUBSTRING(column_name, character_to_remove)`

Solution,

```
SUBSTRING(d1_val, 3)
```

Note: you can use it on SELECT or UPDATE statement